# Can we access Apex Controller class from a separate .js file?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, javascript-remoting

I have a separate `.js` file and I want to access controller properties and functions using that file but as far as I know we must have a `.vfp` page and a controller attribute is given to `apex:page`, but here I don't have a `.vfp` page. I just have a `.js` file.
Is this possible?

Comment: Is it lightning or classic

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is possible. You can use [AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm) and [Apex AJAX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_and_ajax.htm) (part of AJAX Toolkit)

e.g. login example

```
try{
  var result = sforce.connection.login("myname@myemail.com", "password");
  log("logged in with session id " + result.sessionId);
}catch(error) {
  if (error.faultcode.indexOf("INVALID_LOGIN") != -1) {
    log("check your username and passwd, invalid login");
  } else {
    log(error);
  }
}
```

your apex method should be exposed as `webservice` and class should have `global` access modifier.

```
global class myClass{ 
   webservice static String getContextUserName() {
        return UserInfo.getFirstName();
   }
}
```

example of calling such apex method

```
var contextUser = sforce.apex.execute("myClass", "getContextUserName", {});
```

Comment: This isn't a VF controller/extension, though. Perhaps if you had easy access to a RemoteAction method, I would consider this a viable answer.